# No module named "common.finders"

Tags: python, flask, frameworks, package, python-import

I want to run a site project on *flask* in my localhost and I have these problems with packages:

```
from flask import Flask, Blueprint, g, abort
from flask_login import LoginManager
from flask_babel import Babel
from flask_uploads import configure_uploads
from common.finders import Finder, FinderModifier
from common.users import get_user_by_id, get_user_by_token
import filters
import files
import views
```

I think my problem is exactly in these 2 important package lines:

```
from common.finders import Finder, FinderModifier
from common.users import get_user_by_id, get_user_by_token
```

When I run the project the displayed error is as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/my/path/project", line 5,in <module>
 from common.finders import Finder, FinderModifier
ImportError: No module named common.finders
```

Comment: Check whether `common` module is available, try exporting it inside a Python Interpreter.

Comment: Is common a folder?

Comment: Can you post your project tree ? If common is a folder you need to have a __init__.py in it so that python will consider it as a package then you can import from it.

Comment: you can  visit  this link you will found   a photo of the file project https://jpst.it/13FBv

Comment: i was  try this  command but the  same error:    export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/my/path/project

Answer (score 0):

The error says: "ImportError: No module named common.finders"

It means that:

- The package "common" exists (it is a directory with an `__init__.py` file),
- The **module** "finders" doesn't exist (no file named `finders.py`),
  or the **package** "finders" doesn't exit (no directory named `finders` or missing `__init__.py` file in it).

Check your directory structure, you must have:

```
common/
+-- __init__.py
\-- finders.py
```

Or:

```
common/
+-- __init__.py
\-- finders/
    \-- __init__.py
```

**EDIT**

To debug, you can display the path of the `common` module. Try this:

```
python

>>> import common
>>> print(common.__path__)
```

Then look into this path...

Comment: i don't find the common   directory  but  i was find a  file named finder.py  in admin  directory

Comment: @HaithemDISSEM: EDIT: How to debug

Answer (score 0):

I had to install the 'common' module via pip:

`pip install common`

Then things started working.